# How to export Page Builder pages or templates?

Tags: magento2, import, export, page-builder

I need to export pages or templates made with Magento's Page Builder and import them to another site. Is there some way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

Don't listen to any of these people saying that it isn't doable with stock Magento. You just need to be slightly creative as in all programming. It's relatively easy in fact.

1. Enter your CMS page from the Magento admin and save your page (built with Page Builder) as a template.
2. Go to your previous site's database (phpMyAdmin or whatever you use to navigate MySQL) and find the pagebuilder_template table.
3. You should see the names of your saved templates. Export the necessary templates from MySQL into a CSV or SQL file.
4. Go to your new site's database and find the pagebuilder_template table once again and import those CSV/SQL files. These will be identical to your old site.
5. Enter Magento's admin again and navigate to your new CMS page and apply the template.

That's all that is required to migrate. Depending on how you stored your media you may need to move some images/videos around or do some re-linking.

Hope this helps! (tested with Magento ver. 2.4.3-p1)

-Rees

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I'd rather avoid as many 3rd party modules as possible.

Comment: I completely agree, good luck!

Comment: For an  "enterprise" product in 2023, this is downright embarassing, but +1 for this answer because it does, eventually, provide the desired result.  But, wow.  ::shakes head::

Comment: Haha, trust me I had similar thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you try using [data patch scripts](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/data-patches.html).

For many developers these can be pretty intimidating at times though.

A simple module built by [Mark Shust](https://github.com/markshust) to make creating these much easier can be found here: https://github.com/markshust/magento2-module-simpledata

For third party modules, the only one I have found which specifically supports PageBuilder is FireBear's [Improved Import & Export for Magento 2](https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html)

Please report back the solution which worked best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn’t have this option. You need to look for third party modules.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-import-export-cms/

Answer (score 0):

For me work venustheme/magento2-setup - [github](https://github.com/venustheme/magento2-setup).

You can it also install with composer -
composer require venustheme/magento2-setup
But will installed version 1.0, and i use more extensions from venustheme and have a new version of venustheme/magento2-setup.

However, version 1.0 work same way fine, tested on magento 2.4.3 and 2.4.3-p1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this Builder by Magento did not has such a function.

May I suggest using this extension instead in advance https://github.com/Goomento/PageBuilder It's a Free, Opening Source, and of course, the Import/Export function came up as a default functionality alongside others

Comment: This looks interesting. It is like Elementor for Wordpress. I have to test that on some test installation. Thanks for the tip.